# Dynamic Aspx Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for way to build up my aspx page based on a the count of children a parent has.

For example parent 1 has 2 kids he will get 2 pictures and 2 times detailed information about each child in a table.

The parent is logged in and I can count the Foreign keys, so I know how many children the parent has.

The thing I am not sure about is on how to build the html for example using javascript...
What I have now:
My aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/styles/app.js")%>"></script>
```

```
        <div id="myform">
          <div id="myDynamicTable">
            <input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="Javascript: addTable()">
            to create a Table and add some data using JavaScript
        </div>

</div>
```

app.js page:

```
function addTable() {

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");

var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border = '1';

var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '75';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Naam: "));

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '75';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Macharis "));

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '75';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Voornaam: "));

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '75';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Jos: "));

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '150';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Geboorte Datum: "));

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '150';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("22/01/2005: "));

        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

}

Altough this does nothing dynamic and only adds a static table when I click the button.
Any tips are more than welcome!

Comment: Can you give more details? HTml and js code you tried? In this way we can help you better.

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.freelancer.com/

Comment: This is just basic aspx web development. No javascript required. You really need to show what you have done so far.

Comment: I updated the question, altough I am not sure if this is the right aproach for what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got this far

I am able to dynamically add tables, pictures and buttons based on how many children 1 parent has.

Now I want to get the information for all these children out of the corresponding table "TKIN". So i can fill the corresponding fields on my aspx page.

So far I am not sure what is the best approach is but
I am trying to extract the data by List<"TKIN">:

the function:

```
public List<DAL.TKIN> GetAlleKinderen(int ouderid)
{
    var query = (from kindjes in dc.TKINs join x in dc.TOUD_KINs on kindjes.KindId equals x.fkKindId where x.fkOuderId == ouderid  select kindjes).ToList();
    return query;

}
```

Hoping this will return the children for the parent who is logged in and where i know the Id from.

The ASPX.CS file:

```
OuderDAL Ouder = new OuderDAL();
public int id;
public int Kindid;
public DAL.TKIN[] kindjes;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // string idkind = (string)Session["id"];
    //Label1.Text = idkind;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string naam = User.Identity.Name;
        // getting the name of the logged in user

        //Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Ouder.getaantalkinderen(naam));
        this.id = Ouder.getaantalkinderen(naam);
        DataBind();
        // get the amount of children to dynamicly build my aspx page this parent has     //Id is a bad name convention

        DAL.TOUD parent;

        if (Ouder.GetCompleteOuder(out parent, naam))
        {
            kindjes = Ouder.GetAlleKinderen(parent.Ouderid).ToArray();
            //alert("1ste waarde: " +  kindjes.ElementAt(0));
            //Kindid = Convert.ToInt32(kindjes.ElementAt(0));
            //Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(kindjes[2]); --> I have no idea how to get the children out...


        }
        else
        {


        }



    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Maybe better to use DataTable
[how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)